# What is the best practice to large scale dynamic select and where query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

My current objective is creation of a dynamic select and where query. In our case we have a reference table. Reference table is contains references column values and table name. We create a dynamic query on the other table(s) with these references. For example:

```
select * from {table} where {pk1} in (...) and {pk2} in {...}
```

There was a problem in this generated query. The problem is some rows are returns in the result but they are not in query because in queries are different conditions.

Changed sql generation to like this

```
select * from {table} where ( {pk1}=(value1) and {pk2}=(value2) ) or ( {pk1}=(value3) and {pk2}=(value4) ) ...)
```

In this case the problem was solved but query execution time is not good instead of "IN" query. It is about 10-20 times slower. And the query string too big instead of "IN" query.

We can not use the table valued queries because we can not create a new TYPE for each table dynamically and the columns are not same type and order. And new table types may be inserted in future.

So, what is the best practice to do this?

Regards

Comment: How much value  are there "in" clause? for example {pk1} in (1 , 2, 3, ......, 10000)

Comment: It is depends on the referenced table. We have about 50k max rows in a one table currently.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can use temp table for "in" statement like this,

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tid') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tid( Id BIGINT);
    INSERT INTO #tid (Id) VALUES (1), 
        (2), 
        (3), 
        (4), 
        (5), 
        (6), 
        (7), 
        (8),
         --......
        (10000);
    END
select * from {table} where {pk1} in (SELECT Id FROM #tid);
```

this usage faster then "in(1,2,3,4,..., 10000).

Comment: He/she's asking about SELECT statements. For INSERT and UPDATE statements you can use batches.